# Set Label Color in Swift Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

In (iOS) SWIFT I want to pass the label color via a variable and specifically an array. I calculate a number (my index) and then I want to lookup inside an array which contains the color strings, select a color and pass it on to the `UIColor` part of the Label definition:

instead of

```
myLabel.textColor = UIColor.green
```

// Swift requires explicit definition of color "green"

I want

```
var Tcolor = ["green", "blue", "red"]
var index: Int = 1

myLabel.text = "myLabel Text"

myLabel.textColor = UIColor.Tcolor[index]
```

//this should produce the same result as above but programmatically. However, it

returns error with comment "Tcolor is not a UIColor member"...

Is there any other way around?

Comment: You could instead change it to, `var Tcolor : [UIColor] = [UIColor.green, UIcolor.red, UIColor.blue]` and then use it like you are.

Answer (score 2):

`var Tcolor = [UIColor.green, UIColor.blue, UIColor.red]`

See your error `Tcolor is not a UIColor member`. your Tcolor is `string` while `myLabel.textColor` needs `UIColor`

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of `UIColor` not strings

```
var Tcolor : [UIColor] = [UIColor.red, UIColor.blue, UIColor.green]
var index: Int = 1
myLabel.textColor = Tcolor[index]
```

If you need Sting names for the colors you can do this:

`Tcolor : [String : UIColor] = ["Red" : UIColor.red, "Blue" : UIColor.blue, "green" : UIColor.green]`

Color by friendly name?

`let Tcolor_red = Tcolor["Red"]`

OR

`myLabel.textColor = Tcolor["Red"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
let colors = [UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.09, blue:0.32, alpha:1.0), UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.80, blue:0.02, alpha:1.0), UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.81, blue:0.62, alpha:1.0), UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.56, blue:0.00, alpha:1.0)]

myLabel.textColor = color[2]
```